# Dynamically building Ember components from server text

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

This scenario is hypothetical (sort of) but bear with me:

Imagine that I have a server that manages all communications from clients and customers. A client can send me an email via standard means (outlook, gmail, etc) and I will receive it. My server will parse it and store it as an html string.

```
 <div>Hello world</div>
 <div>Second Line</div>
 <img width="10px" height="10px" src="https://mysquare.com/square.png">
 <img width="10px" height="20px" src="https://myrectangle.com/rectangle.png">
 <div>That picture is great</div>
```

Then when I query for the conversation I receive a list of messages back, which in turn each have their inner html defined above. But sadly none of them have the wonderful trappings of ember :(

Now say that hypothetically I would have liked to wrap that image into its own component, let's say to make its source and dimensions dynamic.

```
{{dynamic-img width=imageWidth height=imageHeight src=imgSrc}}
```

Ideally I would separate out the images and extract the relevant key-value pairs, then throw that handlebars templating into the dom and (assuming I had a `dynamic-img` component already defined) it would work. However this is not the case.

How can I automagically convert this html text into ember components? Let's say that I have no access to the server.

> ember, ember-data, ember-cli => 2.9.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you could have a loop in your template

```
{{#each images as |image|}}
    {{dynamic-img width=image.width height=image.height src=img.src}}
{{/each}}
```

And then after parsing the html, create "images" array in your controller with the list of items with parsed data.

Comment: Now I feel dumb for not thinking of that. Thanks a ton!